# How to retrieve a count from the same table inside a BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a large table (3.6M), which consists of 5K to 8K records inserted daily (DataSet), these are a daily snapshot of a 'request'.  I want to add the number of times the unique reference has been seen in previous DataSets.
The key fields here are `ID`, `DataSetID`, `RequestReference`.

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.calcRefPrevSeen=(SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CNT from db.tblrequests WHERE DataSetID<NEW.DataSetID and RequestReference=NEW.RequestReference);
END
```

I have an Index with {DataSetID, RequestReference}.

This is however proving too inefficient and is taking too long due to the number of records.  Is there a better way to update this value within a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the `count()`ing every time, which is **very** expensive, I'd recommend to hold this data in a separate table. On your table create an after insert and an after delete trigger. In this triggers you simply do a

```
/*pseudo code...*/
INSERT INTO my_count_table VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE my_counter = my_counter + 1;
/*or - 1 of course for the delete trigger*/
```

Read more about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).